# What should be done to have permits to join two modules of a project without using sudo?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, permissions

I am trying to link two modules created by me, in a project created with Node.js, and as always I did: `npm link .` inside the module that I want to call, and from the other call it in package.json, and it gives me the following error:
`npm ERR! path /home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db\' -> \'/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/miguel/cursos/cursoJs-Node/proyectoMichaelgram/michaelgram-db',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/michaelgram-db' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/miguel/.npm/_logs/2018-07-17T12_02_46_081Z-debug.log`

How should I install Node globally?
I have seen those files and they are owned by root. I put a new version of Ubuntu 18.04 I installed node Could it be problem when installing node? I do not remember how I did it, but on previous occasions I did not have this permission problem. I do not know if I should uninstall node and npm I have to install it in a way that I can access from any project I do. I already gave another file problems and I corregi using `sudo`, but it does not seem like a practice, because it should not give problems, never gave them node. What do you advise me to do to correct the problem and access node_modules without using `sudo`? Maybe I should uninstall and install it in another way? Thank you, I hope you understand my need, forgive the syntax but I must use the translator. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you the 2 definitive ways given in the npm documenation

1)Reinstall npm with a version manager (recommended)

2)Change npm's default directory manually.

please visit https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: I install it with nvm and it works, thanks @Vaibhav Kumar Goyal. All day I have this problem.

Comment: Happy to help :)